# iCheck not working with knockout

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, icheck

I am using a pure css plugin of [iCheck-bootstrap](https://github.com/bantikyan/icheck-bootstrap) v1.07 along it with [knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) v3.4.2. When using iCheck without knockout, the checkboxes render perfectly. However, when I add knockout and bootstrap, the two don't seem to work together. I have pasted a snippet of my code below. Please help with what I need to correct?

```js
function model() {
  var self = this;
  selectOne = ko.observable(true);
  selectTwo = ko.observable(false);

}

var mymodel = new model();

$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(mymodel);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bantikyan/icheck-bootstrap/master/icheck-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>




<div class="checkbox icheck-default">
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: selectOne" />
  <label>Select One with iCheck</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox icheck-default">
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: selectTwo" />
  <label>Select One with iCheck</label>
</div>
<hr />
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: selectOne" />
  <label>Select One w/o iCheck</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: selectTwo" />
    <label>Select Two w/o iCheck</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

seems to be working fine,  maybe your cdn for icheck isn't working correctly.  I'm using `https://cdn.rawgit.com/bantikyan/icheck-bootstrap/master/icheck-bootstrap.min.css`

```js
function model() {
  var self = this;
  selectOne = ko.observable(true);
  selectTwo = ko.observable(false);

}

var mymodel = new model();

$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(mymodel);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/bantikyan/icheck-bootstrap/master/icheck-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>


<div class="checkbox icheck-default">
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: selectOne" />
  <label>Select One with iCheck</label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox icheck-default">
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: selectTwo" />
  <label>Select One with iCheck</label>
</div>
<hr />
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: selectOne" />
  <label>Select One w/o iCheck</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: selectTwo" />
  <label>Select Two w/o iCheck</label>
</div>
```

Comment: It partially worked as the CSS shows. However, I noticed that I can't click on the box with iCheck.